# Problem with clang compiler with libc++ on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, clang, libc++

I wrote a program (using coroutines), and tried to compile it with clang 9 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, but I get this error:

```
$ clang++-9 -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++2a coroutins_iterator.cpp 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++abi
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I compile my program? What is going wrong?

I installed libc++ with

```
sudo apt-get install libc++-dev
```

Comment: @walnut, i installed it dy "sudo apt-get install libc++-dev"

Comment: On Ubuntu? Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @walnut, Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: @walnut, yes, that's helped me, thx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed the wrong version of libc++, it seems. From what I can tell `libc++-dev` refers to version 6, not 9, in the Ubuntu 18.08 repositories. For Clang 9 you would want to install the corresponding version of libc++:

```
sudo apt-get install libc++-9-dev
```

This should also install the matching version of libc++abi.